# what are a few opera browser specific css tags?

Tags: css, opera

where can i find a list of opera specific css tags? 
I have searched on google for hours and cannot find a list of them. I do know that they start with `-o- {   }`

Answer (score 8):

Look at http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto29/css/o-vendor/

Answer (score 2):

http://caniuse.com/ is a great site for checking which properties are supported in all browsers and which require a vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Some are `background-image: -o-linear-gradient`, `-o-transform:`, and `-o-transition:`. Most properties work without prefixes in Opera, such as: `column-count:`, `background-size:`, `text-shadow:`, `box-shadow:`, and `border-radius`.